# Switching between data providers (Flex 2.0)

Tags: apache-flex

Suppose I have one combo box and I am switching its data provider from `oldDataProvider` to `newDataProvider` with ActionScript. Both data providers are ArrayCollections. Then, when a change occurs in the `oldDataProvider` ArrayCollection, it affects the combo box, although it is not its data provider anymore. Specifically, when removing an item from `oldDataProvider` (in the range of the `newDataProvider` values), it decreases the `selectedIndex` value of the combo box by one, changing the selected item.

Is it a good practice to switch data providers like that? I suspect this is the root of the problem. Or is it better to have only one data provider and adjust its values accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's a bug of ComboBox component and it still exists in Flex 3. You should file it to Adobe bug tracking database.
Here is an extended ComboBox class which should solve the problem:

```
package test
{
import mx.controls.ComboBox;
import mx.events.CollectionEvent;

public class FixedComboBox extends ComboBox
{
    public function FixedComboBox()
    {
        super();
    }

    override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
    {
        if (collection)
            collection.removeEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, collectionChangeHandler);
        super.dataProvider = value;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Now it works as it should, thanks a lot. I reported it as bug as well.